# Bulk update with different values in django 1.11

Tags: django, django-models

I have been reading [the official documentacion of django 1.11 about bulk updating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once). My problem is that I have only seen how to update the fields for ALL the query objects. What I need is a bulk update but with different values, depending on a condition.

Let me write an example. Let's say I have the following model:

```py
class A(models.Model):
    key = models.ForeignKey(SomeOtherModel, db_index=True)
    value = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

As you can see, the `field_definition` points to another model. What I want is to mass update the objects of a query of the model A based on that value. Something like this:

```py
A.objects.filter(key__id__in=[1,2,3]).update(value_for_id_1="1", ..., value_for_id_n="n")
```

The only thing I have seen so for is this syntax:

```py
A.objects.filter(key__id__in=[1,2,3]).update(value="1")
```

Any idea if this is even possible? How can I make this query efficient?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but it seems that you want to reference another column of the same line for each updated item.

It's possible in SQL, so it is with Django, with the help of `F` objects.

```py
from django.db.models import F
A.objects.filter(key__id__in=[1,2,3]).update(value=F("key"))
```